# getting build error - clientbuilder.sslsocketfactory not supported on jdk 9+ in eclipse oxygen with jdk 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I am using eclipse oxygen(4.7) with jdk 1.8. I dont have java 9 on my machine. When i am trying to run my code , its always showing `error occurred during build - clientbuilder.sslsocketfactory(sslsocketfactory) not supported on jdk 9+`

Its also showing error mark on pom file but there is no error inside pom file. I am not understanding this bug.

I have tried few ways but none is working and i am not understanding why its giving this error when i am not using jdk 9 at all. Please let me know what can be done to resolve this issue which is not getting resolved since a week now.

Comment: Do you have *any* versions of Java newer than 8 on your machine?

Comment: Hi , no i have java 8 only - precisely java 1.8.0.251

Comment: What error is being shown for your pom?

Comment: `An internal error occurred during : "Updating maven project". clientbuilder.sslsocketfactory(sslsocketfactory) not supported on jdk 9+`